# filtering result of ls command to get only certain file names based on a format

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I have a directory pointed by `g_inboundDir` which contains following files:
`XAI-001-20170709-123456791.pdf
YXAI-001-20170709-123456791.pdf
001-20170744-123456791.pdf`

`Variable g_filPfix="XAI"
Variable g_fileExt=".pdf"`

Now I want to pick each file which starts with XAI and process it for this I wrote the following command:

```
for i in `ls ${g_inboundDir}/* | grep -E '^${g_filPfix}-([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{8})-([0-9]{9})${g_fileExt}$' 2>/dev/null`
```

I was hoping to receive only XAI-001-20170709-123456791.pdf file but I am not getting any file.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! It is generally a [really bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs") to parse the output of `ls`.  You should probably look into either using `find` or simple shell globbing to get your list of files to process.  Extensive further reading on the subject can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -E '^${g_filPfix}-([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{8})-([0-9]{9})${g_fileExt}$'
```

The immediate issue here is that the pattern for `grep` is wrapped in single quotes, so the shell will not expand the variables `g_filPfix` and `g_fileExt`. Replacing the quotes with double-quotes would fix that. (and you don't need the parenthesis in the pattern.)

Parsing the output of `ls` like that may be problematic with filenames that have whitespace or some odd characters. In particular, a filename with a space in the middle would be taken as two file names.

If you don't actually need such a strict pattern, you could just process
all files with the given prefix and suffix:

```
for f in "$dir/$prefix"*"$suffix" ; do 
    somecmd "$f"
done
```

If you do need the strict pattern, some shells (like Bash, which you probably have on Linux) can do the regex match without external tools. So, to loop over all files in the directory and ignore the files that don't match the pattern:

```
for f in "$dir"/* ; do 
    [[ "$f" =~ "/$prefix"-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{8}-[0-9]{9}"$suffix"$ ]] || continue
    somecmd "$f"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't parse `ls`.

```
for file in "${g_inboundDir}"/XAI*.pdf; do 
    things_to "$file"
done
```

Comment: `things_to` nice name for a user function ! :-) PS: @steeldriver seems to be right.

Comment: I have corrected the answer; good catch (:

Answer (score 0):

Don't grep ls. Use find and regexp instead:

```
find ${g_inboundDir} -regextype sed -regex "^${g_filPfix}-([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{8})-([0-9]{9})${g_fileExt}$"
```

At the end you can use -exec to do something with those files.
Check [man find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to find out more about find :)